# fetch json data to tableview in swift 5

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to fetch data from php file in json to my tableview in swift 5
I am able to get the data in the console as json array,
what I want is to fetch the data into my custom cell but I am not getting the json data array keys for example data["user_id"] it is not loading anything

[my json data one array sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J5zx.png)

```
     func getUsers() {
        
        AF.request(SiteUrl).validate().responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation Successful)")

                    if let json = response.data {
                        do{
                            let data = try JSON(data: json)
                            let str = data
                            print("DATA PARSED: \(str)")
                        }
                        catch{
                        print("JSON Error")
                        }

                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        
     }
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
        
   }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
       cell.textLabel?.text =  "Hi Hadi"
        
        //customCell.AdTitle.text =

       return customCell
   }
```

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: It doesn't look like you assign anything to your property `data`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Comment: You need to reload your tableView once your parsed your JSON. Also, avoid using `print("JSON Error")`, instead `print("JSON Error: \(error)")`.

Comment: Not related, but in Swift5, it might be better to use Codable instead of SwiftyJSON, and in general to use Custom Struct instead of Dict/array for JSON parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's highly recommended to drop `SwiftyJSON` in favor of `Codable`.

Nevertheless just create a data source array, assign the received data to the data source array and reload the table view. In `cellForRow` get the item from the array and assign the values to the corresponding UI elements

```
var data = [JSON]()

func getUsers() {
    
    AF.request(SiteUrl).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("Validation Successful)")

                if let json = response.data {
                    do{
                        let jsonData = try JSON(data: json)
                        self.data = jsonData.arrayValue
                        self.tableView.reloadData() // we are already on the main thread
                        print("DATA PARSED: \(jsonData)")
                    }
                    catch {
                        print("JSON Error", error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count        
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
   let item = data[indexPath.row]
   cell.textLabel?.text = item["user_id"].string
   return cell
}
```

---

And this is the modern way, first create a struct (you have to add the other members according to the JSON and use camelCase names: `"user_id" -> userId`)

```
struct User : Decodable {
    let id, contactName : String
    let userId : String
}
```

and replace the other code above with

```
var users = [User]()

func getUsers() {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    AF.request(SiteUrl).validate().responseDecodable(decoder: decoder) { (response : DataResponse<[User],AFError>) in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let result): 
                print("Validation Successful)")
                self.users = result
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case .failure(let error): print("JSON Error", error)
        }    
    }
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count        
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
   let user = users[indexPath.row]
   cell.textLabel?.text = user.userId
   return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks @vadian I got this errors Cannot assign value of type 'JSON' to type '[JSON]' for                             self.data = try JSON(data: json)
and this error Cannot find 'str' in scope for print("DATA PARSED: \(str)")